# How do I use the dictionary object to find and combine the data from duplicate headers in a sheet

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, duplicates

I'm trying to take the data as it exists in the first image (with markups), put it in a dictionary object (which I just learned about), look for duplicate headers (In this case the "P8" entries), Then take the duplicates and combine them with the first occurrence of that header, then go and delete the sections associated with the duplicate headers. The second image (no markups) is how the data should look when it's all said and done. Notice that "pinlables:[] now has multiple instances of the data combined in the duplicates combined into a single instance.

This is the code I've managed to cobble together (I'm not a programmer by any stretch of the imagination, The last VBA program I wrote was 5 years ago and it took me forever, I just got stuck with this task because as little as I know, it was the most out of our small team) I know its missing some critical elements such as loading the keys properly, that's because I can't quite understand how to do it from the articles and code I've read. I know the general organizational steps I'm just kinda lost with how to use the dictionary object and make it work with the correct looping. So I have tried to comment in the missing sections to identify what I think needs to happen. It may also be worth noting that the data in this sheet has a very specific formatting of spaces, commas, brackets etc because my final output is a .yml input file that feeds into another program. So if I can preserve the formatting that would be great.

```
    Sub AltDictSort()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim Dn As Range
Dim n As Long
Dim nRng As Range
Dim tempDN As String
Dim TxtRng As Range

Set Rng = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
For Each Dn In Rng
    If .Exists(Dn.Value) Then
         
    'not sure this next line does what I'm intending
    tempDN = .Item(Dn.Value).Offset(2, 0) 'load Dn.Value into temp value should be something like "   pinlabels: [J2-1,J2-2,J2-3]"
    
    Dn.Value = Left(tempDN, Len(tempDN) - 15) 'Strip 15 characters from left to get "J2-1,J2-2,J2-3]"
    tempDN = Dn.Value
    Dn.Value = Right(tempDN, Len(tempDN) - 1) 'Strip 1 characters from right to get "J2-1,J2-2,J2-3"
    tempDN = (Dn.Value + "," + Dn) 'add the two strings together to get something like this "   pinlabels: [J2-1,J2-2,J2-3,J-4,J-5,J-6]"
    
    'now I need to put the combined string back into the spot of the first occurrence of a pinlabels duplicate (in this specific case A8) but need to identify location of first occurrence
    
    'now I need to delete the entire second occurrence ( second P8: and next two rows with mpn and pinlabels) no idea how to do this
    
    Else
    'I don't think anything needs to happen here but I'm not completely sure????
    End If
Next

End With
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

@JohnnieL This is what the input data looks like as text though it seems to lose the formatting when posting.

```
> connectors:   Startup-R-J2:    mpn: 436450310    pinlabels:
> [J2-1,J2-2,J2-3]
> 
>   P8:    mpn: D38999/20JE26PN    pinlabels: [P8-C,P8-D,P8-E]
> 
>   Startup-R-J1:    mpn: 436450310    pinlabels:
> [J1-4,J1-9,J1-3,J1-6,J1-7]
> 
>   P8:    mpn: D38999/20JE26PN    pinlabels: [P8-G,P8-H,P8-I,P8-J,P8-K]
> 
>   Startup-R-J3:    mpn: 170-009-272L000    pinlabels: [J3-3,J3-2,J3-1]
> 
>   P8:    mpn: D38999/20JE26PN    pinlabels: [P8-R,P8-S,P8-T]
> 
>   PTO1-J2:    mpn: 170-009-272L000    pinlabels: [J2-5,J2-6]
> 
>   P8:    mpn: D38999/20JE26PN    pinlabels: [P8-A,P8-B]
> 
>   PTO3-J2:    mpn: 170-009-272L000    pinlabels: [J2-8,J2-7]
> 
>   P8:    mpn: D38999/20JE26PN    pinlabels: [P8-N,P8-P]
> 
>   PTO3-J2:    mpn: 170-009-272L000    pinlabels: [J2-3,J2-4]
> 
>   P8:    mpn: D38999/20JE26PN    pinlabels: [P8-R,P8-S]
> 
> cables:   Startup-R-J2_P8:    wirecount: 3    gauge: 20 AWG    length:
> 100 mm    color_code: IEC
> 
>   Startup-R-J1_P8:    wirecount: 5    gauge: 22 AWG    length: 200 mm 
> color_code: IEC
> 
>   Startup-R-J3_P8:    wirecount: 3    gauge: 24 AWG    length: 300 mm 
> color_code: IEC
> 
>   PTO1-J2_P8:    wirecount: 2    gauge: 26 AWG    length: 400 mm   
> color_code: IEC
> 
>   PTO3-J2_P8:    wirecount: 2    gauge: 28 AWG    length: 500 mm   
> color_code: IEC
> 
>   PTO3-J2_P8:    wirecount: 2    gauge: 30 AWG    length: 600 mm   
> color_code: IEC
> 
> 
> connections:
> -
>   - Startup-R-J2: [J2-1,J2-2,J2-3]
>   - Startup-R-J2_P8: [1-3]
>   - P8: [P8-C,P8-D,P8-E]
> -
>   - Startup-R-J1: [J1-4,J1-9,J1-3,J1-6,J1-7]
>   - Startup-R-J1_P8: [1-5]
>   - P8: [P8-G,P8-H,P8-I,P8-J,P8-K]
> -
>   - Startup-R-J3: [J3-3,J3-2,J3-1]
>   - Startup-R-J3_P8: [1-3]
>   - P8: [P8-R,P8-S,P8-T]
> -
>   - PTO1-J2: [J2-5,J2-6]
>   - PTO1-J2_P8: [1-2]
>   - P8: [P8-A,P8-B]
> -
>   - PTO3-J2: [J2-8,J2-7]
>   - PTO3-J2_P8: [1-2]
>   - P8: [P8-N,P8-P]
> -
>   - PTO3-J2: [J2-3,J2-4]
>   - PTO3-J2_P8: [1-2]
>   - P8: [P8-R,P8-S]
```

Comment: @dhnobles Hi could you maybe paste as text here the input data? I'd love to help but not 100% sure on input data: Is it the rows 1 through 26 on the first worksheet screen cap? thanks

Comment: The loop should add items to the dictionary when they don't exist, and the items you add should have enough metadata to allow the next iteration to find out where to insert rows; by storing `Range` objects into the dictionary (keyed with `Dn.Value` e.g. "P8") you'll have that metadata, and then there's no need to delete any rows, because you'll only output the rows you need, where you need them. Another way to go about this would be to model the data with objects, make 1 "reader" loop that collects all the data, then a "process" loop that processes it, then a "writer" loop that outputs results

Comment: Does the data come from a text file? Then there is no reason to import it into an Excel sheet first. This will be some kind of data exchange format that has a fixed structure, right? Another question. Why is it so important to use a dictionary? It may be that it works well with it and I'm sure I'm just one who has an idea about that. But there are probably just as surely other approaches that work just as well.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, Sorry, I'm not sure how to ask a targeted question like that because I really don't know what I'm doing very much at all and frankly I'm not sure exactly what I need because I don't know what I don't know. Just trying to find help where I can. So then can you help with populating the dictionary object? I'm confused as to how that is done as the examples I've found were vague.

Comment: I have a draft of an answer on the way with an alternative approach, but @Zwenn is right that you probably don't really need a `Dictionary` here, and if the input is actually a text file then you can open it from the code and process the raw text (without Excel mangling dates and long numbers, although that doesn't look like it's a problem with this particular data).

Comment: @Zwenn the data I have comes as the output of a bunch of other code I've spent the last month piecemealing together. The original input is a build sheet we use. I take the data from specific areas of the original sheet and though a lot of tedious (for me at least) code I output it to the sheet its on (the one in the pics) with very specific formatting that is then saved as a text file with a .yml extension to feed into the other program we use. The issue is that the program we feed this information into is very particular about how the input data is formatted.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon

You and Zwenn may be right that this doesn't need a dictionary object. I was searching for a way to do this and someone suggested that this was a perfect usage of the dictionary so I started trying to figure out how to use it. For some reason I'm having more trouble than usual in wrapping my head around the usage. I'm trying to use the dictionary because frankly I don't know how else to go about it.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon If you are working on a solution, I will wait for it. Got a few other things in the pipeline anyway ;-)

Comment: dhnobles, if it needs this further processing now, I'm pretty sure the previous processing of the data is suboptimal. I don't know where the source data comes from and in what form it is available from the source. But if different goals are being pursued with this data, then it would make the most sense to first convert it into a standard format. Many people have racked their brains over such formats and therefore they can be processed relatively easily for different purposes.

Comment: @Zwenn I can pretty much guarantee you that the previous code is sub-optimal at best and is more likely downright clunky. As I've said, I'm not a programmer, I'm just doing my best to make this work from examples I find on the internet, helpful comments from blogs, and my very limited experience with VBA. I'm 100% sure that this could have been done somewhere in that previous code but I had no idea how to do it so my supervisor said to get the data out and formatted and then look at how to clean it up afterwards. So thats where I'm at now.

Comment: dhnobles, you are a hardworking person, no question! I don't know what time it is with you right now. For me it's 7:10 pm. As an employee, I'm no longer working at the moment. I'm not a programmer either, but I've acquired some knowledge because I'm interested in software development. Would you like to share what the original data looks like and also the VBA code that you are using to process this data so far? Then also what is to be done with the data. It may well be that you achieve your goal with @MathieuGuindon's solution. At this point, I am simply interested in the overall context.

Comment: Note: all supplied code is untested air-code (should still work lol); you'll very likely need to adjust the reader function to match your format (maybe the code should consume an extra empty line before the next block, for example).

Comment: @Zwenn I don't mind sharing the source and the code. Here is a link to my google drive. For some reason the file gives some link errors when I open it, not sure why.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w2vPWLDNRBX74zEG0AAhOgVTx9-Y1hsj/view?usp=sharing

When you click the button the output file (.yml) will be saved the directory where you put the workbook. There should be 5 modules contained in the WB.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thankyou for this, I'm going to spend a little while trying to understand your code does and see if I can figure out how to adapt it for my application. It may take a little while (maybe even overnight) so don't think I just bailed out.

Comment: A bit of a side note from this post. Is there a good place to go to find freelance programmers for little jobs like this? I'm pretty sure if something like this come up again I'm going try and find someone who actually knows what they are doing to write the code instead of me fumbling around for a month or more. I'll pay for it out of my own pocket if I have to.

Answer (score 4):

I'd start with a class module that might look like this - let's call it `ConnectorInfo` for now:

```vb
Option Explicit
Public ConnectorID As String
Public MPN As String
Public PinLabels As New Collection
```

The idea is to model the data we're looking at; each "object" represented in the output has a "ConnectorID" value ("P8", "Startup-R-J1", "PTO3-J2", etc.), a MPN value ("436450310", "170-009-272L000", etc.), and a number of pin labels that need to be combined, so there needs to be code that can turn this `PinLabels` collection into a string that separates them with a comma and wraps the list with square brackets.

So let's add a public function to that class module, that does exactly this by copying the collection into an array, then using the `VBA.Strings.Join` function to produce the list of pin labels:

```vb
Public Function CombinePinLabels() As String
    ReDim result(1 To PinLabels.Count) As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To PinLabels.Count
        result(i) = PinLabels(i)
    Next
    CombinePinLabels = "[" & Join(result, ",") & "]"
End Function
```

Since the input is going to be reading the PinLabels as strings, we need a procedure (since we're in a class module we can dub it a "method") that will splice them for us, while making sure none of the labels are duplicated; we can do this by keying the collection items (no need for a dictionary since we aren't actually accessing the keys):

```vb
Public Sub ParsePinLabels(ByVal inputValue As String)
    'expect inputValue to look like "[123,456,ABC-123,XYZ-000-ABC]"; assert that (i.e. break here before we make a mess):
    Debug.Assert Left$(inputValue, 1) = "["
    Debug.Assert Right$(inputValue, 1) = "]"
    
    'strip the prefix and brackets:
    Dim parsed As String
    parsed = Mid$(inputValue, 2, Len(inputValue - 2))

    Dim values As Variant
    values = Strings.Split(parsed, ",")

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(values) To UBound(values)
        On Error Resume Next 'prevent blowing up when key already exists
        PinLabels.Add values(i), values(i)
        On Error GoTo 0 'important!
    Next
End Sub
```

Notice the input logic and format is essentially irrelevant here: the processing that needs to happen is independent of the input format *and* of the output format.

So let's build the output then.

> [...] my final output is a .yml input file that feeds into another program.

Definitely toss the idea of manipulating Excel objects: what you want is to make your code generate a .yml text file.

The code that processes the input will be giving a collection of `ConnectorInfo` objects to the code that produces the output, so we already know we'll need a procedure for that. In a standard module (e.g. `Module1`), you want to have a procedure like this:

```vb
Public Sub GenerateOutputYML(ByVal connectors As Collection)
    Dim connector As ConnectorInfo
    For Each connector In connectors
       'TODO
    Next
End Sub
```

But, we need it to output to a particular file name - let's take it in as a parameter and worry about how we supply it later:

```vb
Public Sub GenerateOutputYML(ByVal filePath As String, ByVal connectors As Collection)
    Dim handle As Long
    handle = VBA.FreeFile

    On Error GoTo CleanFail 'MUST handle errors when dealing with filesystem I/O
    Open filePath For Output As #handle
    Print #handle, "connectors:"

    'use ForEach..Next loops to iterate object collections
    Dim connector As ConnectorInfo
    For Each connector In connectors
       'each Print # statement writes a line to the text file,
       'Spc() function writes the number of specified spaces to control indentation.
       Print #handle, Spc(2) & connector.ConnectorID & ":"
       Print #handle, Spc(4) & "mpn: " & connector.MPN
       Print #handle, Spc(4) & "pinlabels: " & connector.CombinePinLabels
       Print #handle 'leaves an empty line between connectors
    Next

CleanExit:
    Close #handle
    Exit Sub
CleanFail:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

Now all that's left to do, is to parse the input into such a `Collection` of `ConnectorInfo` objects. You can do this like you're doing by opening the text file in Excel and then iterating cells - or you can programmatically open the text file in-memory with a similar `Open` statement, and that can live in a function that takes a filename and returns the collection the *output* function wants to work with:

```vb
Public Function ParseInput(ByVal intputFilePath As String) As Collection

    Dim handle As Long
    handle = VBA.FreeFile 'gets an available file handle
 
    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    Open inputFilePath For Input As #handle 'never hard-code the handle!

    Dim currentLine As String
    LineInput #handle, currentLine 'read the first line
    Debug.Assert currentLine = "connectors:" 'right?

    Dim contents As Object 'early-bound: As Scripting.Dictionary (requires library reference)
    Set contents = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'early-bound: = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim currentItem As ConnectorInfo
    Dim currentKey As String

    Do Until EOF(handle)

        LineInput #handle, currentLine
        currentKey = Left$(currentLine, Len(currentLine) - 1) 'strip the colon char

        If contents.Exists(currentKey) Then
            'we have seeen this ID before; fetch it
            Set currentItem = contents(currentKey)
        Else
            'new ID; create a new info object
            Set currentItem = New ConnectorInfo
            contents.Add currentKey, currentItem
        End If

        'assumes MPN is the same for all duplicates of a given ConnectorID

        LineInput#handle, currentLine
        currentItem.MPN = Mid$(currentLine, Len("mpn: "))            

        LineInput#handle, currentLine
        currentItem.ParsePinLabels Mid$(currentLine, Len("pinlabels: ["))

    Loop

    'at this point the items dictionary should contain all the ConnectorInfo objects we want to output.
    'GenerateOutputYML wants a Collection, so we iterate the array returned dictionary's Items function
    Dim result As New Collection

    Dim i As Long 'use a For..Next loop to iterate arrays
    For i = LBound(contents.Items) To UBound(contents.Items)
        result.Add contents.Items(i)
    Next

CleanExit:
    Close #handle
    Set ParseInput = result
    Exit Function
CleanFail:
    MsgBox Err.Description 'for debugging; user doesn't need to see this
    Set result = New Collection 'return an empty collection on error
    Resume CleanFail
End Function
```

The missing piece is a macro that knows where to get the input file, where to save the output file, and calls the reader and writer procedures - now that we've abstracted away all the gory details, we're left with a clear high-level story to tell:

```vb
Public Sub ParseYML()
    Const inputFile As String = "C:\Path\Input.txt"
    Const outputFile As String = "C:\Path\Output.yml"

    Dim connectors As Collection
    Set connectors = ParseInput(inputFile)

    If connectors.Count > 0 Then
        GenerateOutputYML outputFile, connectors
        MsgBox "File '" & outputFile & "' was generated successfully for " & connectors.Count & " connectors."
    Else
        MsgBox "No data was read from the specified input file."
    End If

End Sub
```

This isn't the only viable approach, but as a general rule of thumb it's a very good idea to clearly separate the data itself (`ConnectorInfo`) from the input and output: having the data intertwined with the input that's being read all while the output is being generated, might work... but easily gets difficult to tweak afterwards.

By separating parsing the input from producing the output, you can more easily isolate exactly what code needs tweaking, without necessarily affecting other parts of the code.

Comment: Note: If the file paths can't be hard-coded, you may want to use `Application.GetOpenFileName` to prompt the user for a path to use.

Comment: So I've been messing with this code for two days now and I can't for the life of me get it to run. I figured out some of the syntax errors (Line Input as two words instead of LineInput) after a bit but it still keeps getting caught up on one thing after another.

Can you actually Dim a variable as another variable? This kicks out a Type not defined error.
Dim currentItem As ConnectorInfo

currentLine wasn't dim anywhere and was throwing an undefined error so I added 
Dim currentLine as String 'I think its supposed to be a string???

I'm struggling at wrapping my head around it all.

Comment: @dhnobles `ConnectorInfo` is supposed to be the name of a *class module* in your project, that looks like the first snippet at the top. If your class module's name is `Class1`, press F4 to bring up the *properties* toolwindow and you'll see a `(Name)` property with the value "Class1" - change it to "ConnectorInfo".

Comment: The `CombinePinLabels` and `ParsePinLabels` procedures are members of the `ConnectorInfo` class module. Then there's a *standard module* that could be `Module1`, with the `ParseYML` macro and the `ParseInput` function (which could then be `Private`) and the `GenerateOutputYML` sub (could also be `Private` if it's in the same module as the `ParseYML` macro/procedure).

Comment: @dhnobles again my apologies for the untested code (the idea is less to provide copy-paste-ready 100% working code and more to illustrate how to break things down into different scopes and modules, i.e. how to structure a small program, clearly separate concerns, and avoid a spaghetti mess; the old *fishing rod vs fish* tale, if you will), but I [assure you](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/66015406/1) that `currentLine` was declared in this post, despite any typos (notice how I *systematically* declare locals immediately before their first use? [in/out of loop body is another debate!]) ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, That helps me understand the structure a little better. I've never even used a class module before, only ever a standard module.  I'm going to spend some more time with this today and see if I can work out my issues. I completely understand that the code isn't necessarily meant to be copy paste, I'm just struggling a bit here understanding what I need to do to adapt the code, or at least the concept, to my needs is all, your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

### Combine Strings Using Dictionary

- Adjust the values in the constants section. Note that if you use the same cell addresses, the data will be overwritten.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub AltDictSort()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const FirstCell As String = "A2"
    Const dstCell As String = "B2"
    Const setsLen As Long = 4
    
    ' Define Source Range.
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim wrCount As Long ' Worksheet Rows Count
    With Range(FirstCell)
        wrCount = .Worksheet.Rows.Count
        Set rg = .Resize(wrCount - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("pinlabels:*", , xlFormulas, xlPart, , xlPrevious)
        If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Set rg = .Resize(rg.Row - .Row + 2) ' + 1 because last empty row
    End With
    
    ' Define Sets Count.
    Dim SetsCount As Long: SetsCount = rg.Rows.Count / setsLen
    If rg.Rows.Count Mod setsLen > 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Write values from range to array.
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = rg.Value
    
    Dim rCount As Long ' Result Rows Count
    
    ' Write values from array to dictionary, and back to array.
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        
        Dim arrString() As String: ReDim arrString(1 To 2)
        Dim m As Long: m = 1
        
        Dim n As Long
        Dim iniString As String
        
        For n = 1 To SetsCount
            iniString = Data(m, 1)
            If .Exists(iniString) Then
                arrString = .Item(iniString)
                arrString(2) = combineString(arrString(2), Data(m + 2, 1))
            Else
                arrString(1) = Data(m + 1, 1)
                arrString(2) = Data(m + 2, 1)
            End If
            .Item(iniString) = arrString
            m = m + setsLen
        Next n
        
        rCount = .Count * setsLen
        ReDim Data(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
        m = 1
        
        Dim Key As Variant
        
        For Each Key In .Keys
            Data(m, 1) = Key
            Data(m + 1, 1) = .Item(Key)(1)
            Data(m + 2, 1) = .Item(Key)(2)
            m = m + setsLen
        Next Key
    
    End With
    
    With rg.Worksheet.Range(dstCell)
        .Resize(wrCount - .Row + 1).ClearContents
        .Resize(rCount).Value = Data
    End With

End Sub

Function combineString( _
    ByVal str1 As String, _
    ByVal str2 As String, _
    Optional ByVal lChar As String = "[", _
    Optional ByVal rChar As String = "]", _
    Optional ByVal Delimiter As String = ",") _
As String
    Dim lPos As Long: lPos = InStr(1, str1, lChar)
    Dim lStr As String: lStr = Left(str1, lPos)
    Dim r1Pos As Long: r1Pos = InStr(1, str1, rChar)
    Dim rStr As String: rStr = Right(str1, Len(str1) - r1Pos + 1)
    Dim m1str As String: m1str = Mid(str1, lPos + 1, r1Pos - lPos - 1)
    Dim r2Pos As String: r2Pos = InStr(1, str2, rChar)
    Dim m2str As String: m2str = Mid(str2, lPos + 1, r2Pos - lPos - 1)
    combineString = lStr & m1str & Delimiter & m2str & rStr
End Function
```

Comment: I get a "Invalid procedure call or argument" when that code hits this line:  Dim m1str As String: m1str = Mid(str1, lPos + 1, r1Pos - lPos - 1)

I've been trying to debug it but haven't figured out where the error is.

Comment: There is nothing to debug at the moment. The code is very sensitive concerning the strings. They have to contain one opening `[` and one closing `]` bracket. If they don't, the code will fail. Note also the data has to be in 'four-cell sets'. First cell will be the Key, the second cell doesn't matter (it will just be copied from the first occurrence), the third cell will contain the brackets, and the fourth will be empty. If you cannot produce the data in this format, the code is useless. If you can explain what is different in your data than in the data of the image, I can try to modify.

Comment: Here is a copy of [my file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m-f2Mk0XwfJir7T3VjeOgBgCQ6cC5Lh6/view?usp=sharing) on Google Drive. Maybe seeing my sample data will give you an idea.

Comment: I think I get what your saying, I'll try and see if I can make the relevant modifications once I get a decent grasp of your code. If you want to see an actual example grab the file from my google drive link below and click the generate yml button. It will spit out a yml (text) file in the same folder as the xlsm file. That output is the data I'm trying to manipulate in the fashion described in the post.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w2vPWLDNRBX74zEG0AAhOgVTx9-Y1hsj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If I click the button in the `Example` worksheet, it creates a file. In that file, select the cell above the first occurrence of `cables` (denoting the beginning of a different format), delete to the bottom and you're god to go. Note that the cell above `cables` is not empty (it is blank). The `Find` method will find it, and do the offset, and exit the sub because the number of rows will not be divisible by 4. Optionally you could change `xlFormulas` to `xlValues` when it will not find it, or just do `+ 1` instead of `+ 2`.

Comment: Ha, ha, ha. I found a simple fix: just change to `.Find("pinlabels:*", , xlFormulas, xlPart, , xlPrevious)`, which will find the last occurrence of `"pinlabels:"`.

Comment: Can you explain to me why it stops comparing things after the first section of data? Is it looking for row sets of 4? I need to have it do the same kind of comparison to the full sheet not just the top section. If you look in the example it would be the last two groups at the bottom PTO3-J2 occurs twice for example so I need to combine J2-8, J2-7, J2-3, J2-4. I'm trying to modify for that but I'm confused as to what controls the comparison stopping after the first section.

Comment: I have edited the code. It now contains the changes I proposed in the previous comment. It still works on my end: `J2-8,J2-7,J2-3,J2-4`.

Comment: When I run the code it only seems to look at the first section of the data, see images. All of the data below about row 49 seems to be completely ignored and isn't in the output. I'm trying to understand what controls that.

[Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/ViKldv7.jpg)

Comment: It is supposed to ignore the rest of the data. The code covers only what you have presented in the first two images. The rest of the data is of a different structure. Only the range from the first cell to the last cell containing `"pinlabels"` is processed. I wasn't aware that the rest should also be processed. Sorry for disappointing you.

Comment: I apologize, I think you're misunderstanding me, I'm not disappointed, I'm just trying to understand how it works and what I can do to modify it to make it do what I need. I'm immensely grateful for all the help I've gotten from you and the others. I didn't even realize when I posted originally that it would take a different structure to do each section or I would have tried to present the issue better.